# Spring Data Mongodb & Spring Boot - autowiring MongoRepository from Mongolab

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, mlab, mongorepository

Let say I have a simple mongoRepository below:

```
public interface LettersRepository extends MongoRepository<Posts, String> { 

    }
```

I'm connecting to Mongolab. The collection name on Mongolab has to be 'letters' for the autowiring to work.

Now, I don't want to call my collection on Mongolab 'letters'. 
I want to call it 'mails'.

How do I use annotations to configure that the autowiring will point to the 'mails' collection instead?

I tried the annotation `@Repository(value="mails")` above the interface but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapping to Mongo collections depends on your domain object, not the repository. If you want your `Posts` class to be stored in the collection `mails`, annotate it with `@Document`:

```
@Document(collection = "mails")
public class Posts {
}
```

See the [Mapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-chapter) chapter in the documentation for details.

Comment: Thanks - i will try this shortly and let you know once its working. +1